# Yii2 set custom session

Tags: php, session, yii2

I want to add costum session and session values query from user table (database)

where I put `Yii::$app->session->set('blabla','1234')`?

If I put in login controller and user is set auto login (not access login), the session can't set

Comment: Check whether session is opened or not like Yii::$app->session->isActive. if not then open $session = Yii::$app->session; $session->open().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `app\components\User` component you could just hook to the `afterLogin` event

example:

```
namespace \app\components;

Class User extends \yii\web\User{
   public function afterLogin($identity, $cookieBased, $duration){
      parent::afterLogin($identity, $cookieBased, $duration);
      Yii::$app->session->set('blabla','1234')
   }
}
```

ref http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html#afterLogin()-detail

Answer (score 0):

put in your config/main.php or web/main.php with 'on afterLogin'

```
'components' => [ 
...
   'user' => [
        ...
        'on afterLogin' => function($event) {
            if($userId = Yii::$app->session->get('__id')){
                $user = User::findOne($userId);
                Yii::$app->session->set('username', $user->username);
                Yii::$app->session->set('name', $user->name);
                ...
            }
        }
    ],
```